# Prevent automatic native image generation (ngen) of specific assembly

Tags: .net, ngen

It seems that .NET 4.5.2 automatically generates native images of assemblies as it sees fit in some circumstances. Is there a way to prevent it from generating a native image for a specific assembly? (The reason I'm asking is that this particular assembly is encrypted/obfuscated, and for some reason it does not work when ngen'd).

Comment: Where did you read .Net 4.5.2 ngens the assembly automatically? Post the link to the article.

Comment: I read it here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2011/09/17/improvements-in-the-clr-core-in-net-framework-45/
But also I noticed the problem due to the fact that the assembly was ngen'ed, without having done so manually (to my knowledge) on a Windows 8 machine.

Comment: It is done with your obfuscated assembly itself. That shouldn't make any difference. It your obfuscated code works, ngen'd assembly also should work.

Comment: I agree that it *should* work... but it doesn't.  The code breaks down when the assembly is ngen'd, and if removed from the ngen-directory, it works again. (The assembly is encrypted using Agile.NET)

Comment: "Breaks!!" that doesn't gives much information to speculate. What way it breaks? What you observe? Explain in detail please.

Comment: Well, I have obseved a couple of strange behaviors. In this case I get a NullReferenceException that does not occur when the assembly is either unencrypted, or not ngen'd.  I couldn't tell you exactly where it occurs, since I cannot debug the encrypted assembly, but is seems to be a method that returns a constant byte-array that returns null, even though this should not be possible.

Comment: If at all that doesn't work, it is either a bug in .net auto ngen feature or with Agile.NET(maybe that creates something which shouldn't be). Report the bug in connect.microsft or agile.net once you confirm what is the problem. I know this doesn't help you here but you may need to report the bug.

Comment: The feature is real, it is a .NET 4.5 feature and only works on Windows 8.  It is very poorly documented, it is supposed to just get the job done without having to tweak any knobs.  It is called the "Auto NGEN Maintenance Task".  The only real angle I see to avoid your problem is to not store the assembly in the GAC.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Agile.NET. We are moving away from that product, since it has caused problems before.
@Hans, so you're saying that not storing the assembly in GAC prevents automatic ngen?

Comment: Yes.  This is standard obfuscator lossage.  The only one that's ever slowed-down by them is the dev that has to keep his code running.